# Pass parameters from servlet to jsp using HTTPServletRequest return null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web.xml

I'm trying to pass parameters from servlet to JSP using HTTPServletRequest but no luck. Someone can explain me where am I wrong?

Here the servlet:
**HelloServlet**

```
package net.codejava;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloServlet
 */
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response)
                         throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setAttribute("name", "name1");
        request.setAttribute("surname", "surname1");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

}
```

Here the JSP:
**JSP ("HelloServlet/index.jsp")**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>HelloWorld Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome <%= request.getAttribute("name") %>
</body>
</html>
```

and the web.xml:
**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>helloservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.codejava.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
        <jsp-file>/HelloServlet/index.jsp</jsp-file>        
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>helloservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/HelloServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**RESULT**

```
Welcome null
```

Comment: try using request.getSession().setAttribute and request.getSession().getAttribute

Comment: @NishadKAhamed What a random solution. Don't just throw solutions. Do you know the reason for current behaviour ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ this is not a solution, i just give a suggestion to check if that works or not. That is why i just commented instead of posting it as an answer. Also, please try to think an answer the question instead of wasting time in finding mistakes.

Comment: @NishadKAhamed No, It doesn't work.

Comment: @NishadKAhamed I don't say anything, if you are sure that, "Finding mistake is a waste of time"

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yes, sometimes

Comment: put System.out doGet method and check please. Jsp file may Direct calling.

Comment: @Trenza try using response.sendRedirect("index.jsp") for redirection instead of requestDispatcher

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt Could You explain better? What do you mean?

Comment: @NishadKAhamed No I'm sorry. No luck.

Comment: are you sure the Helloservlet is being called? <jsp:file> tag remove. You already have requestdistpacher. finally, where do you keep jsp files.

Comment: To clear out a terminology mistake: those things are called attributes, not parameters. Look, the method is named `setAttribute()`, not `setParameter()`.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your action is never get called.
Try changing the following parts in your code.

Updated **web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>helloservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>net.codejava.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
   </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>helloservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and call your action by

```
http://localhost:8080/HelloServlet/index.htm
```

Comment: why I need to call htm file instead of jsp?

Comment: its not a file, just a action path. You can chnage it to any value in web.xml url mapping. Its just a sample.